# SWiSH alternative Flash animator for AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, flashdevelop, flash-cs5

In the past I've used SWiSH to create small animations that I could use for Flash projects, however, I'm now trying to move to writing AS3 which SWiSH doesn't support.

Whilst I have access to Flash CS5 through work, it doesn't have much in the way of in-built effects & animations, compared to SWiSH's 400+, and I want to be able to create various effects quickly and easily. (I'm a coder, not a graphics kind of guy!)

So, does anyone know of a good alternative to SWiSH (Flash Animator) that I could get/purchase that has a lot of stock animations/effects built into it, but is fully compatible with AS3, allowing me to export symbols in SWF and embed/use them in FlashDevelop?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the animations are frame-based (not scripted), you can embed AS2 SWF assets into an AS3 project.

The best way is probably to [embed symbols](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html) from your SWF files, like this:

```
[Embed(source='SWFFileName.swf', symbol='symbolName')]
```

If you just create animations and maybe have some frame-labels to jump to, this is going to work fine. It won't work if you have scripted animations, since all AS2 code will be lost when embedding.

It's probably good practice anyway to have plain animations without scripting and let the actual game code control the animations.